# will svn mirror of mirror be affected when master changes?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a repo-mirror-b which is an svn mirror of repo A. I also have repo-mirror-c which is a mirror of repo-mirror-b. Now am taking down the repo-mirror-b and creating a new repo-b(with the same UUID as repo-mirror-B).
repo-mirror-c should now mirror new repo-b.

Am using the same repository name for repo-mirror-b and repo-b and same UUID.

Should I change any settings for repo-mirror-c or will it be unaffected by this change? Should I restart the system where repo-mirror-c is hosted? Should users delete all checkouts of repo-mirror-c and checkout fresh?

Anything else that I should be careful about?
Thanks!